# Unable to select English (UK) speech in Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: windows-10, cortana, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices

I have a Windows 10 Enterprise machine where

- *Country or region* is set to *United Kingdom*
- Languages includes *English (United Kingdom)*

But still the only speech language available is *English (United States)*

I also have one Server 2016 with the same problem and one where I have British English available.

Doe's anybody here know how to enable the *English (United Kingdom)* language for speech?

Comment: What have you tried to do to fix this so far?

Comment: Tried with clean install of os and remove and add British English. I have and suspicion that the problem occurs if the machine not connected to internet when the British English language pack is added. But haven have time to investigate further. Will do soon.